# Listview with section headers

Tags: android, android-listview

I am working on a listview that shows a restaurant order.

[image]

As you may see, each row has 4 items:

1. Units
2. Article + Group
3. Unit price
4. Total price

What I need to create section headers to group the items by Group.

In this case, the resulting list should look like:

PRIMEROS

1  CAMPARI-RICARD.   3.50  3.50

2OS

1 MENU INFANTIL      15.50 15.50

BEBIDAS

4 LIMONADA CASERA.   3.30  3.30

1 CAMPARI-RICARD.    3.50 3.50

This is my adapter code:

```
  public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter         //has a class viewholder which holds
    {
        public class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtUnidades,txtArticulo,txtPrecio, txtBaseImponible;
            ImageView imageView;
        }

        public List<ListaLineasTicket> parkingList;

        public Context context;
        ArrayList<ListaLineasTicket> arraylist;

        private MyAppAdapter(List<ListaLineasTicket> apps, Context context) {
            this.parkingList = apps;
            this.context = context;
            arraylist = new ArrayList<ListaLineasTicket>();
            arraylist.clear();
            arraylist.addAll(parkingList);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return parkingList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) // inflating the layout and initializing widgets
        {

            View rowView = convertView;
            MyAppAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content_lineas_ticket, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new MyAppAdapter.ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.txtUnidades = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtUnidades);
                viewHolder.txtArticulo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtArticulo);
                viewHolder.txtPrecio = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrecio);
                viewHolder.txtBaseImponible = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtBaseImponible);


                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (MyAppAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            // here setting up names and images



            String unidades = parkingList.get(position).getUnidades();

            String filename = unidades;     // full file name
            String[] parts = filename.split("\\."); // String array, each element is text between dots

            String beforeFirstDot = parts[0];
            System.out.println( "hola  dos lineas unidades "+ beforeFirstDot );

            viewHolder.txtUnidades.setText(beforeFirstDot );
            viewHolder.txtArticulo.setText(parkingList.get(position).getDescripcionarticulo()+" "+ parkingList.get(position).getGrupo());
            viewHolder.txtPrecio.setText(parkingList.get(position).getPrecioventa());
            viewHolder.txtBaseImponible.setText(parkingList.get(position).getBaseimponible() );


            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

What do I need to create this section headers?

Comment: @MurilloComino, no. There are 6 or 7 groups that should be the section headers, and there can be lots of items, each item belongs to a group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way this can be done is by using a layout with the header and the item already in place and then changing the visibility if the header is the same.

you can refer this example.

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/primary"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="This is section header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/section_header"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:text="example text" />

    <!-- more views can go here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter :

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.DataViewHolder> {

    private List<Contact> mData;

    @Inject
    public RecyclerAdapter() {
        mData = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setData(List<Contact> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public Contact getItem(int position){
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new DataViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Contact contact = mData.get(position);
        holder.headerTextView.setText(contact.getName().substring(0, 1));
        holder.nameTextView.setText(contact.getName());

        // if not first item check if item above has the same header
        if (position > 0 && mData.get(position - 1).getName().substring(0, 1).equals(contact.getName().substring(0, 1))) {
            holder.headerTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.headerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.section_header)
        TextView headerTextView;
        @BindView(R.id.list_item_name)
        TextView nameTextView;

        public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```